# No setter/field for User class

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I get this problem when I generate the APK it was shown in the installing from the android studio but it disappears later
This problem shown in all classes I have its objects in the firebase

I set the setter/getter and I read a lot of question but it still

```java
public class User {

//This is the key of users child in the firebase
    static final String USER_CHILD = "Users";
    private String ID;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public User() {}

    public User(String ID, String name, String email) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getID();
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

EDIT FIREBASE JSON TREE

```
{
  "ali" : {
    "email" : "any4@gmail.com",
    "id" : "ali",
    "name" : "mohammed ali"
  },
  "ali3" : {
    "email" : "any3@gmail.com",
    "id" : "ali3",
    "name" : "hhhhhjjj"
  },
  "mo_dev" : {
    "email" : "any2@gmail.com",
    "id" : "mo_dev",
    "name" : "mokah"
  },
  "mok" : {
    "email" : "any1@gmail.com",
    "id" : "mok",
    "name" : "mohammed"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some errors that you have been encounter?

Comment: Please show us your database structure. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales no errors only this

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks dude I added it as JSON tree

Comment: The problem is because of the inconsistency of your field names. Check to duplicate to see how to solve this.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry dude but the problem still and the Object when I send it Firebase changes the fields to a,b,c,e,f what is this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677651/hashmap-object-saved-in-cloud-firestore-with-field-names-as-letters-insted-of-in?noredirect=1#comment101827817_57677651) out.

Comment: @AlexMamo I solve it with `@Keep` above the class and I do what in that link
Thanks so much

Comment: @Mohammed Good to hear that. You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your class try putting this first above the class:

```
@Keep
```

You can also add this to your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class com.example.yourapp.YourClass
```

where YourClass is the name of your java object class that is stored to Firebase.

Comment: I add this to User class as
-keep class com.anis.huessien.diys.User
and another class that also I have its object in firebase
-keep class com.anis.huessien.diys.DIY
but it still

Comment: You have to add this in the proguard file and not the class

Comment: yes, I added it in proguard-rules.pro

Comment: I used `@Keep` above the class and it is working Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to know that