# Release build app crashes cause of proguard rules

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, proguard

I have a bunch of Recycler views in my app that gets data from the firestore database. Everything went fine in my debug app but when I added `minifyEnabled true` In my proguard everything worked fine but the activity hosts recycler fails with the below logcat error. I'm totally unaware of how to add the proguard rules for the model classes

I just made my stacktrace and this is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.swf.sahrudhayafoundation, PID: 30519
    java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.swf.sahrudhayafoundation.q.b
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.o0.l$a.<init>(:714)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.o0.l.z(:377)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.o0.l.e(:540)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.o0.l.s(:253)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.o0.l.p(:100)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.i.o(:187)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.z.o(:116)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.i.n(:165)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.z.n(:97)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.b.b(:23)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.b.a(:12)
        at c.a.a.a.a.a(:36)
        at c.a.a.a.c.get(:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.I(:86)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.x(:158)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.y(:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.k(:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.H(:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.I(:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.p(:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.o(:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.d(:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.s2(:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.U1(:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.X0(:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6934)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1455)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:475)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6934)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6934)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6934)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6934)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6934)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:795)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24817)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3361)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2121)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2415)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8204)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1085)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:908)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:835)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1070)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

Comment: You should always provide enough information to enable others to answer your question, like error stack trace and code in this case.

Comment: @EraftYps Please check the updated description in my question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and the content of your model class. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo - you're the guy I'm waiting for. To let you know the answer provided by Bimal Kafle worked I removed changed minifyEnabled to false and it works well now but when I add the same line to true it starts crashing throwing the above logcat posted. I wonder why this happens as minifyEnabled helps to reduce the app size right. I wish you'll clearly explain me in this regard.

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations Good to hear that Bimal Kafle's answer worked. In that case, I think you should take a look at my answer from the following **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948)**.

Comment: @AlexMamo - I'm a little confused about the following line can you please help me clarify what should I replace in the following line of code `-keepclassmembers com.example.YourModalClass.** { *; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have problem because of  proguard, to be sure just try  by disabling minify in your release build type

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        ------
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your proguard rule

```
-keep class package.to.yourmodels.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.*
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations
```