# Why is firebase adding an extra calendar node after publishing my app on playstore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, proguard

After publishing my app with these optimizations;

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
useProguard true
```

Firebase sees my Calendar code from the CampaignModel class as a node and adds it to the data as "c" with all current time details. I have excluded all my class models using Proguard:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.tubevibe.android.models.CampaignModel {*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.tubevibe.android.models.UserModel {*;}
```

[image]

This node c is causing my app to crash when fetching data from the real-time database. Is there a way I can prevent this node from the Calendar from being inserted?

Here is my campaign model

```
package com.tubevibe.android.models;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import java.util.Calendar;

@Keep
public class CampaignModel {
    private String id;
    private String idNo;
    private String videoUrl;
    private String viewsNeeded;
    private String totalCost;
    private String active;
    private String timeRequired;
    private Long postingDate;


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int utcOffset = c.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + c.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

    public CampaignModel() {
    }

    public CampaignModel(String id, String idNo, String videoUrl,
                         String viewsNeeded,
                         String totalCost, String active, String timeRequired) {
        this.id = id;
        this.idNo = idNo;
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
        this.viewsNeeded = viewsNeeded;
        this.totalCost = totalCost;
        this.active = active;
        this.timeRequired = timeRequired;
        this.postingDate = c.getTimeInMillis() - utcOffset;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIdNo() {
        return idNo;
    }

    public void setIdNo(String idNo) {
        this.idNo = idNo;
    }

    public String getViewsNeeded() {
        return viewsNeeded;
    }

    public void setViewsNeeded(String viewsNeeded) {
        this.viewsNeeded = viewsNeeded;
    }

    public String getTotalCost() {
        return totalCost;
    }

    public void setTotalCost(String totalCost) {
        this.totalCost = totalCost;
    }

    public String getTimeRequired() {
        return timeRequired;
    }

    public void setTimeRequired(String timeRequired) {
        this.timeRequired = timeRequired;
    }

    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }

    public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

    public Long getPostingDate() {
        return postingDate;
    }

    public void setPostingDate(Long postingDate) {
        this.postingDate = postingDate;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please share the content of your "CampaignModel" class including the package name. In which place have you added those two lines of code?

Comment: Thank you, Alex, Please check, I have edited. I just don't know why after using minify and shrink resources, it adds the Calendar as a node too. The two lines starting with -keepclassmembers are added to proguard-rules.pro on Android Studio.

Comment: I have decided to remove the Calendar code from the Model and use it in my activity where I push the values to format my posting date before the push. Looks like it is a bad idea to have extra code in the model. I will publish again and check. If it works I will post as the answer. Thanks, @AlexMamo your response led to this.

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works. Write another answer? It's already there, I just wrote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple classes under your "models" package, then you can only use the following line:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.tubevibe.android.models.* {*;}
```

Because I see that you are using the "@Keep" annotation in your "CampaignModel" class, which is correct, the following two lines of code are also mandatory to be added to your "proguard-rules.pro" file:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Right before the above line of code. Remember, you are getting this behavior because you are using Proguard for security, which shuffles the code so others cannot see it, right after you create the app's APK:

- [Firebase firestore variable name changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948)

It's for Cloud Firestore, but the same rules apply.

Moreover, the "Calendar" class is **not** a Firebase Realtime Database [supported data-type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). I have not tested it, but most likely you also need to add the following line:

```
-keepnames class java.util.Calendar
```

If this doesn't work, most likely you should get the "c" object out of your model class and create a new instance of it, only in the class where you need that. In that way, object "c" will **not** be present in the database anymore.

To see it's working, publish the app again with the changed code.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, I will make some changes as you have proposed here.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted ;)

Comment: Yes ( get the "c" object out of your model class ) this has worked. I have published it on the play store and it is posting very well.  I also added the "-keepattributes *Annotation*" statement to proguard-rules.pro.Thank you! :-)

Comment: You're very welcome, kizito, and good to hear that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Alex explained why the `c` shows up in your database, but I'd like to point out two other ways to ensure it doesn't.

1. Mark the field as `private`, which means Firebase ignores it while reading from/writing to the database:

   ```
   private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   private int utcOffset = c.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + c.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
   ```
2. Tell Firebase explicitly to ignore the field while reading from/writing to the database:

   ```
   @Exclude
   private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   @Exclude
   private int utcOffset = c.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + c.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. This seems to be a way around if we still need to keep the calendar code in the model. I haven't tried this yet but will consider testing this as well in the future. It is a great suggestion. :-)