# Android Kotlin + Firestore - DocumentSnapshot.toObject works only on emulator but not after installation

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, apk

I have an Android application written in Kotlin and uses Firestore to read data.

I have this pretty standard code (I believe):

```
firestore.collection("my_collection_name")
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            snapshot.documents?.forEach { document ->
                val myModel: MyModel = document.toObject(MyModel::class.java)
```

This works perfectly fine when I run from Android Studio, **both on the emulator and on my physical device**.
But, when installing through **APK or through Google Play** the **document.toObject** always returns the MyModel object with it's default values. Not null, no error, just an empty object.
I know the data is retrieved well because I can pull it using document.get(). Plus, the number of documents is correct.

Any ideas?

```
Some variables from gradle:

kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.0'
```

Comment: is this happening when you are installing apk with debug buildType or release builtType?

Comment: release.
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

Comment: It's most likely because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948), right?

Comment: Yes. I also think so.This may be happening because of proguard for release build.Add your model class file in progaurd file to keep it from applying.Use the code share by Alex in the comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this proguard thing. Is it a must? can't I just comment it out?

Comment: Thanks Alex and Ranjeet!!! It's working.

Comment: @AlexMamo or Tal Bener Could either of you kindly post the answer below so that others may find the solution?

Comment: Ok, I just did it. Are you willing to accept it?

Comment: Please accept Alex's answer. it is the correct answer and it saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

> when installing through APK or through Google Play the document.toObject always returns the MyModel object with its default values.

Your objects are getting the default values because you are using Proguard for security. This means that once you add your app's APK to Google Play, your code becomes shuffled, so others cannot see it. To solve this, please add the following optimization of code in your build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Then add the following rules in your project's Proguard file to prevent that behavior by replacing the package name with your own package name:

```
-keepattributes Signature //Global rule

-keepclassmembers class com.example.MyModel.** {
  *;
}
```

Please check below for more information:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard

Comment: This should be marked at the correct answer. I found the answer the hard way after wasting 3 days on it. @Tal Bener Please accept this answer. it's a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Please add @Keep annotation to MyModel class.

```
@Keep
class MyModel(..){..}
```