# Newly Created App is not working after Publishing at Google Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It crashes when the login button is pressed. Plz guide how to solve this Problem

The app shows this error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init> (CustomClassMapper.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass (CustomClassMapper.java:12)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean (CustomClassMapper.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass (CustomClassMapper.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass (CustomClassMapper.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue (DataSnapshot.java)
  at com.usama.usamamart.LoginActivity$4.onDataChange (LoginActivity.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange (Query.java:7)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent (ValueEventRegistration.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire (DataEvent.java:2)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run (EventRaiser.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:888)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:213)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8178)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:513)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Comment: You might also take into consideration checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not configured ProGuard correctly to ignore your data classes, that you use to read data from the database.

It's hard to say precisely what you did wrong, given the lack of details in your question, so the best I can recommend is to read the documentation on [configuring ProGuard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard).

Comment: I am sure that I have configured it correctly. The App was working well on the emulator but it caused login problem as I published it. Now it crases as I hit on login button.