# Firestore document not getting written correctly after publishing same app from playstore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when i am installing my app from android studio every thing is working fine I am able to write and read from firestore correctly but when i uploaded my app on playstore i cannot write and read the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWBQQ.png)

as you can see i cannot see the name of the field in my firestore console.
I have added ignore commands in my proguard rules not it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. But it's most likely because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948).

Comment: yeah its the exact problem. thanks

Comment: In that case, I just marked it as a duplicate question.

Comment: i have asked a new question as the solution didn't worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283584/firestore-documents-not-getting-mapped-correctly-after-publishing-app-to-playsto

Comment: When the name of the variable is changed, the ProGuard is responsible for that.  So most likely you didn't add the correct rules.

Comment: I have added both the images of console and proguard rules in my new question . please have a look into that here.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283584/firestore-documents-not-getting-mapped-correctly-after-publishing-app-to-playsto