# Firestore documents not getting mapped correctly after publishing app to playstore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when i am installing my app from android studio every thing is working fine I am able to write and read from firestore correctly but when i uploaded my app on playstore i cannot write and read the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIjeV.png)

as you can see i cannot see the name of the field in my firestore console. I have added ignore commands in my proguard rules not it didn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSrfA.png)

Comment: "I have added ignore commands in my proguard rules not it didn't work." Adding those rules is definitely one way to go. If that didn't work for you, edit your question to show the [minimal code+rules with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @siddharth , you need to set Keep class for your model classes..

Comment: I have added an image of my proguard rules too. though this one is still not working when i updated it on the playstore

Comment: @siddharthsharma Try to use instead of `...entities.Post**{*;}` -> `...entities.Post* {*;}` and also add `-keepattributes *Annotation*` together with @Keep in your POJO classes. Does it work now?

Comment: ok i'll try it, and will report back when it is reviewed by playstore