# Kotlin - Firestore toObject method not working as intended

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-obfuscation

I am using Firestore for my Android project and I am using the following code to convert the fetched document to a custom data class

```
val userData = user.toObject(UserData::class.java)!!
```

Now this line works perfectly when no code obfuscation is happening, however, with obfuscation, this line does not fail but rather does not copy the `user` document data to the `userData`. so I think the issue might be with Firestore and code obfuscation.

Does anyone else have had this issue before?

Comment: I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948) will help, right?

Comment: Yes, it does but I wanted an approach that doesn't keep the class from obfuscating. Thanks for the link though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toObject()` method uses reflection to fill up your `UserData` model from the user document. Now that your `UserData` class is getting obfuscated, Firestore is not able to map the values in document to the model class.

To fix this, you need to disable code obfuscation for all the data models that you are using in Firebase.

The easiest fix is to add a `@Keep` annotation to your data class.

```kotlin
@Keep
data class UserData(...)
```

If you have a lot of such models, you can disable obuscation for an entire file or package by adding more rules to your `proguard-rules.pro`.

For example, this statement will keep all the classes intact inside `model` package while code shrinking and obfuscation:

```kotlin
-keep class com.example.app.data.models.** { *; }
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#keepoptions) for more such rules.