# All field name in firestore be added "$app_debug" strings automatically

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why all fields in my document have the `$app_debug` at the end of its name like this:

[image]

**Update:** Shop is created this way

```
     private var shop = Shop()
     with(binding) {
            shop.name = edtName.text.toString()
            shop.address = edtAddress.text.toString()
            shop.phone = edtPhone.text.toString()
            shop.openTime = edtOpenTime.text.toString()
            shop.website = edtWebsite.text.toString()
            shop.owner = edtOwner.text.toString()
            shop.imageUrl = imageUrl
        }
    shop.pendingApprove = true
    shop.created = false
    shop.lastModifiedTime = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis.toDouble()
```

Here is my way to put data to firestore

```
db.collection(SHOP_PENDING_COLLECTION)
                .document(Firebase.auth.uid)
                .set(shop)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    hideProgressbar()
                    startActivity(Intent(this@AddNewShopActivity, ShopMainActivity::class.java).apply {
                        putExtra(EXTRA_CREATED_SHOP, "created")
                    })
                    finish()
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    hideProgressbar()
                    Utils.showShortToast(
                        this@AddNewShopActivity, getString(R.string.fail_to_create_shop)
                    )
                    Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Error adding document", e)
                }
```

and my `Shop.kt` model

```
@Parcelize data class Shop(
    internal var uid: String? = null,
    internal var name: String? = null,
    internal var owner: String? = null,
    internal var address: String? = null,
    internal var phone: String? = null,
    internal var openTime: String? = null,
    internal var website: String? = null,
    internal var imageUrl: String? = null,
    internal var service: String? = null,
    internal var rating: Double? = null,
    internal var reviewCount: Long? = null,
    internal var location: @RawValue HashMap<String, Any>? = null,
    internal var pendingApprove: Boolean? = null,
    internal var created: Boolean? = null,
    internal var lastModifiedTime: Double? = null,
    internal var fcmToken: String? = null
) : Parcelable
```

I was trying to looking solution but can't find anywhere. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: This might be because you are using Proguard for security. for more details have a look at this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60719948/18265570)

Comment: Please show us how you create the  `shop` object. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @RoopaM tried it but not working :(

Comment: Please add the actual code and not an image.

Comment: @AlexMamo i was changed the code, please check again. Thank you!

Comment: If you log the value of `edtName.text.toString()` do you get the correct value?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, i've checked it and all value are still correct. Just can't figure why the fields name be changed

Comment: Have you tried to remove `internal` from the fields and `@Parcelize`?

Comment: @AlexMamo It worked bro. Thank alot! Please write your answer so other people can read it

Comment: Good to hear that. I just added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize and deserialize objects when using Firestore, then you can simply use Kotlin data classes. This means that there is no need to add `internal` in front of the fields and there is also no need to use an `@Parcelize` annotation.