# Firestore document returns null values for fields only when the app is downloaded from Google Play; not a problem when loaded via Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

My app is currently available only on the Internal test track. It runs without error when launched from Android Studio, but when I upload it to Google Play, delete it from my phone and then download and install it, when I try to start it, the following code returns null for document.get("Best level"), document.get("Best number of words"), document.get("Best word length") and document.get("Play sounds").[image] Here is the code:

```
    private static final String FSBESTLEVEL = "Best level";
    private static final String FSBESTNUMWORDS = "Best number of words";
    private static final String FSBESTWORDLEN = "Best word length";
    private static final String FSSOUNDS = "Play sounds";


    private void getSettings() {
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mDevIDDocRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
  OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
 //        mDevIDDocRef.get(Source.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(new 
 OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                assert document != null;
                if (document.exists()) {
                    // Handle the legacy Best score field, which was a 
                   String.
                    // All the documents that contained a non-blank score 
                     have
                    // already been converted to Long.
                    if (document.get(FSBESTSCORE) instanceof String) {
                        updateFieldType(BEGINNER_TIME/1000L);
                        myScore = BEGINNER_TIME/1000;
                    } else {
                        myScore = (Long)document.get(FSBESTSCORE);
                    }
                    level_val = ((Long) 
            Objects.requireNonNull(document.get(FSLEVEL))).intValue();
                    if (document.get(FSBESTLEVEL) == null) {
                        best_level_val = 0;
                        updateBestLevel(level_val);
                    } else {
                        best_level_val = 
      ((Long)document.get(FSBESTLEVEL)).intValue();
                    }
                    num_words_val = ((Long) 
               Objects.requireNonNull(document.get(FSNUMWORDS))).intValue();
                    if (document.get(FSBESTNUMWORDS) == null) {
                        best_num_words_val = 0;
                        updateBestNumwords(num_words_val);
                    } else {
                        best_num_words_val = 
           ((Long)document.get(FSBESTNUMWORDS)).intValue();
                    }
                    if (document.get(FSBESTWORDLEN) == null) {
                        best_word_length_val = 0;
                        updateBestWordLength(best_word_length_val);
                    } else {
                        best_word_length_val = 
          ((Long)document.get(FSBESTWORDLEN)).intValue();
                    }
                    word_length_val = ((Long) 
              Objects.requireNonNull(document.get(FSWORDLEN))).intValue();
                    order_important_val = (boolean) document.get(FSORDER);
                    if (document.get(FSSOUNDS) == null) {
                        play_sounds_val = true;
                        updatePlaySounds(play_sounds_val);
                    } else {
                        play_sounds_val = (boolean) document.get(FSSOUNDS);
                    }
                    uname = (String) document.get(FSUSERNAME);
                    button_continue.setEnabled(true);
               // If the user name hasn't been set, show the prompt and don't let the user
                    // go to the next page until they've entered one.
                    if (uname == null || uname.length() == 0) {
                        no_screen_name = true;
                        screen_name_prompt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        screen_name_fld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        no_screen_name = false;
                        screen_name_prompt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        screen_name_fld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    savePrefs(myScore, level_val, best_level_val, num_words_val, best_num_words_val, word_length_val, best_word_length_val, order_important_val, play_sounds_val, androidID, uname);
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    createUserDocument();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "getSettings() error" + task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(context, "getSettings() error" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                crashlytics.log(Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage()));
                level_val = sharedPref.getInt(FSLEVEL, 0);
                num_words_val = sharedPref.getInt(FSNUMWORDS, 0);
                word_length_val = sharedPref.getInt(FSWORDLEN, 0);
                order_important_val = sharedPref.getBoolean(FSORDER, false);
                play_sounds_val = sharedPref.getBoolean(FSSOUNDS, true);
                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that produces NPE because we cannot see any `document.get("Best level")` in the shared code.

Comment: @AlexMamo See the above declaration of FSBESTLEVEL.

Comment: Most likely is about [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948), right?

Comment: My buildTypes is identical. Actually, the problem disappeared on its own after awhile. It's been on the Production track for awhile now without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, after a few days, the problem went away and now I'm getting the correct data. Maybe it was a caching issue, I don't know, but so far it hasn't recurred.

Answer (score 0):

please verify if you have add the SHA fingerprint to your project and it is valid

if not please follow these steps and [ref](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en).

> **Add a SHA fingerprint**
>
> Follow these steps if you didn't initially provide a SHA certificate
> fingerprint for your Firebase Android app or if you need to add an
> additional one.
>
> 1. Make sure that you have the SHA fingerprint of your signing certificate.
> 2. In your Project settings, go to the Your apps card.
> 3. Select the Firebase Android app to which you want to add a SHA fingerprint.
> 4. Click Add fingerprint.
> 5. Enter or paste the SHA fingerprint, then click Save.

also you can see your SHA fingerprint your android studio

> 1.Open Android Studio
>
> 2.Open your Project
>
> 3.Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
>
> 4.Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List
> Gradle 5.scripts of your Project)
>
> 6.Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
>
> 7.Click on Tasks
>
> 8.Click on Android
>
> 9.Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar(Sometimes it will be in Gradle Console))

ref [how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode#34223470)